# How to tell if logstash is persisting a queue

Tags: docker, logstash

I'm trying to configure logstash (docker:5.6) to use persistent queues. The simplest way with docker seems to be to configure by environment variables. Currently I am using:

```
        QUEUE_TYPE=persisted
        PATH_QUEUE=/logstash-queue
```

From the documentation, I believe that logstash should interpret these environment variables to set queue.type and path.queue. I see lines in the logs that logstash is creating an empty directory at /var/lib/logstash/queue (the default queue location). However, when I connect to the container I don't see any data being written in either /logstash-queue or in /var/lib/logstash/queue.

I've investigated the monitoring api at localhost:9600 but nothing seems to tell me whether the environment variables have actually been applied.

Is there a way to confirm that logstash is actually using a persistent queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out the issue here. It seems like the docker hub logstash is not configurable in the same way to the logstash in the elastic repo (docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash). After changing to the docker.elastic.co image I can see the data in /logstash-queue